# In Grafana how do I display a text column in the graph view

Tags: grafana

Each of my data points has a unique textual id associated with it.

I can display these fine in table panels but can't find a way to access them in graph panels.

I'd like if these values showed up when I hover over data points in the graph.

I'd also like to be able to use them in a datalink URL.

Are either of these things possible? and if so how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show details on grafana point hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762163/show-details-on-grafana-point-hover)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query based annotation.
Notably these are added to the dashboard not the panel, they apply to all panels in the dashboard.
To do this you need to go into the dashboard settings which is the small gear top right, not the big gear on the left.
https://grafana.com/docs/reference/annotations/#querying-other-data-sources